# Can't determine who can install iOS Application using In House development ?

Tags: ios, enterprise, ad-hoc-distribution, ota, in-house-distribution

I have an Apple Enterprise account using In-House development , but after i share this link in my web-server i discoed that any one can copy this link and share with others , My question here.
How i can set configuration to determine who can download my application through the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you distribute your app through the way of in-House development，you must create a Provisioning Profile with which the user will be authorized to use the application.

So the ios device which is not added into the provisioning profile will not be able to install the app.

For more detail, have a look at http://www.apple.com/business/accelerator/deploy/